# TLS Handshake failure on first page load

Tags: javascript, ssl, https

We have noticed an issue where loading web pages on some CE device browsers (TV, Set-top boxes etc) exhibit an odd behavior:

- When loading first time an HTTPS URL (<https_customer_url>), the page does not load at all (packet capture reveals that TLS handshake fails)
- When loading the same HTTPS URL(from an already loaded page) using window.location = "<https_customer_url>", the exact same HTTPS URL loads fine.

Any advice into what might cause the difference would be very helpful.

Comment: There has to be a reason why the handshake fails. Such reasons include, that the certificate is considered 'invalid', i.e. the issuer is untrusted or the current time is outside of the validity date of the certificate. Usually libraries dealing with TLS have return codes detailing the reason for failure. Can you reproduce the issue with, for example, libcurl?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium thanks. yes, curl <https_customer_url> --verbose  --tlsv1.1 --tls-max 1.2:
NSS error -8179 (SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER)
* Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.

So if that is the reason, we still cannot figure out how come same URL works when loaded using window.location, on same device/browser which apparently "does not recognize the CA" (if we go by the curl output)

Comment: Can you verify, whether the JavaScript call even performs the TLS handshake?

Comment: @Icareus: Different clients behave differently and might have different certificate stores. The effect you get is definitely not with curl, since curl does not have the ability to execute Javascript. Please describe what exactly you see with the specific client. Please provide the packet captures (as pcap, not as screenshot) for the failed and successful case, so that one can compare what is happening.